# How to flash clean install of buster instead of bullseye to SD card

Tags: raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Since the recent release of bullseye, if I do a clean install on an SD card using raspberry pi imager, then I get Bullseye by default.

Due to the changes to the camera functionality in Bullseye, some software does not work. I want to use buster instead until these issues have been resolved.

How do I do a clean install to an SD card of buster instead of bullseye, using raspberry pi imager or otherwise?

Additional info:

I'm working with third party libraries that currently don't work with the camera functionality in Bullseye. If I want to do a clean install for a new Pi, but still use those libraries, then I have to use Buster. This is out of my control until those third party libraries are updated to work with bullseye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: For future reference, http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/ is the website with many Raspberry Pi related images.

If you do not want the 64 bit version of Raspbian Buster, the link for Raspbian Buster is: http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/. Click on the folder of the version of Raspberry Pi OS you want. (Do not pick the last one on the list - that is Bullseye). My recommendation is to pick the second to last download link, the one released on 2021-05-28. After you have clicked on the folder of your preferred version, download the .zip file. For the most recent version of Raspberry Pi OS Buster, the link is: http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2021-05-28/2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf.zip. I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/ to find all releases of Raspberry Pi OS (Older OS in http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/archive/)

These have `.info` files which describe the contents.

Download the file then use the "Other" option of Raspberry Pi imager to install it.

NOTE you really should have a backup of your previous.